# Angular Material Table get Columns

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a pretty big table (a lot of columns). That is why I want to allow the user to change the displayedColumns. My idea is to put all the columns in a MultiSelect. To make it work I need to know all the columnIds to use them as values in the select-options. To make it look nice, I need to know the contents of the columns header-cells to use them as the displayed text of the select-options.

This is what the Table looks like.

```
columns = new FormControl(['name','custom1']);
```

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="custom1">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>My Custom Column</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.custom1}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns.value"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns.value;"></tr>
</table>
```

So the Data that I need for the Options should look like this.

```
const columnOptions = [{columnId: 'name', columnHeader: 'Name'},{columnId: 'custom1', columnHeader: 'My Custom Column'}]
```

This way the Select can look like this.

```
  <mat-select [formControl]="columns" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let col of columnOptions" [value]="col.columnId">{{col.columnHeader}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

I could simply hardcode the `columnOptions` as you have seen above. But as all the required data is present in the MatTable I was wondering if there is any way, to get the options form the Table. I have been asking google for help, there is a lot about MatTable but nothing that explains how to get meta-inforation about the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend defining the `columnOptions` in the component like you have, and then using that to dynamically create the columns in the template. That way it is only defined in one place.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let column of columnOptions">
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column.columnId">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ column.columnHeader }}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column.columnId]}}</td>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Trying to go the other way, and query for the columns from the template would be messy and slower.